# PHP server on PC

Tags: php, web-services, xampp, ip

I want to make a php application and it must host in a computer and open from many branches of my schools using web.

I installed `XAMPP` on my pc server, and if i try to open the application in the same LAN network it works, but if i change the network it is not working.

The browser say that ip 192.168.1.22 take large time to load and not open.

how can i config that problem please

Comment: [The manual for access control in apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

Comment: If the application is only present on the LAN network and not on the internet. You can't connect to it over the internet.

Comment: Assuming the 2,3,4 subnets are bridged, you should be able to edit 'httpd.conf` and add the other subnets using `Require 192.168.2` and `Require 192.168.3` etc using only the first 3 of the 4 quartiles to signify ALL IP's on that subnet

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a static IP on your machine, then set your router to forward ports so that all requests that come to your router on a particular port would be forwarded to your machine. This should do for testing purposes, but if you want to host a website for example you will need to get a permanent static IP for your router, this usually costs money from your ISP(internet service provider).

Comment: He is not trying to access from the internet, he is trying to access from a different subnet of his network.

Comment: In this case setting up a static IP on your machine and forwarding ports on a router should do for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.22 is your **local** IP address, you cannot access it from a different network. You can get your external IP address for example using [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/). Also, if you are behind a router, you have to open and forward the port which is used by your web server to your machine.